# How would I write a script that reads a series of strings, and outputs in an HTML5 textarea only those strings beginning with the character “b.”?

Tags: javascript, string

I need to write a script that reads a series of strings and outputs in a textarea only those strings beginning with the character “b.”

I was using the split element to create individual tokens, but I don't know how to then search the created tokens. I need it to take the words out of an inputed sentence in browser, and return only those that begin with the letter "b"

What function should i use to search the tokens created from the split function, or is there an easier way to search the sub-strings to print out the results I need?

```
    function findStrings(inputString) {
  var inputArray = [],
  inputArrayLen,
  holdArray = [],
  pat = /\bb/i;

  inputArray = inputString.split(" ");
  inputArrayLen = inputArray.length;

  for (var i = 0 ; i < inputArrayLen; i++) {
    if (pat.test(inputArray[i])) {
      holdArray.push(inputArray[i])
    }
  }
  return holdArray.join(',')

var inputString = document.getElementById( "inputField" ).value
var results = document.getElementById( "results" );

var outputString = findStrings(inputString)

results.innerHTML = "<p>The sentence split into words is: </p>" + 
"<p class = 'indent'>" + outputString + "</p>";
}



// register click event handler for searchButton


function start()
{
   var splitButton = document.getElementById( "splitButton" );
   splitButton.addEventListener( "click", splitButtonPressed, false );
} // end function start

window.addEventListener( "load", start, false );
```

Comment: Read a series of strings from where? Formatted how? What do you mean by "token"--is it the same as "substring"? What is a "split element", do you mean "split function"--you were splitting on what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this function to search a string and return a string containing all words that begin with a b or B.

```
function findStrings(inputString) {
  var inputArray = [],
  inputArrayLen,
  holdArray = [],
  pat = /\bb/i;

  inputArray = inputString.split(" ");
  inputArrayLen = inputArray.length;

  for (var i = 0 ; i < inputArrayLen; i++) {
    if (pat.test(inputArray[i])) {
      holdArray.push(inputArray[i])
    }
  }
  return holdArray.join(',')
}
```

Then you could add it to the HTML like this

```
var inputField = document.getElementById( "inputField" );
var results = document.getElementById( "results" );

function splitButtonPressed (){
    var inputString = inputField.value,
        outputString = findStrings(inputString);

    results.innerHTML = "<p>The sentence split into words is: </p>" + 
    "<p class = 'indent'>" + outputString + "</p>";
}


// register click event handler for searchButton


function start() {
   var splitButton = document.getElementById( "splitButton" );
   splitButton.addEventListener( "click", splitButtonPressed, false );
} // end function start

window.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", start, false );
```

Comment: Like this? 
Check the question

Comment: Do you mean for me to do this like in my question?

Comment: The way you were doing it called a splitButtonPressed function but there was none defined. I edited my code, this should work.

Comment: Where are you testing it?

Comment: In Google Chrome browser off of Brackets Coding

Comment: It worked here, but had to set JSFiddle to nowrap to make the window.addEventListener work https://jsfiddle.net/9r18u51L/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the chatAt function.

```
for (i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    var mystring = tokens[i];
    if (mystring.charAt(0) == 'b') {
        // append to textarea 
    }
}
```

charAt(0) gets the first character of a string. Do that for each of your substrings.

Comment: Ohhh, I get it now! Thank you! but how will it print individual strings?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but to add it to the textarea try: document.getElementById("mytextarea").value += mystring

Comment: Make sure you're looping through all of your tokens and have that if statement inside the loop

Comment: I'm still new at java programming. Can I do a for loop to loop through or??

Comment: How do I insert my code onto here so that I can show you the issue I am dealing with? @LionKing34

Comment: @ChristopherWitt Edit your question and click the {} button in the editor

Comment: I get that much now.. I'm just not uderstanding how when I prompt the user in browser for the sentence, its only going to just output the "b" words.

Comment: I must not understand what you mean by append to text area?

Comment: @ChristopherWitt Use the code from my first comment

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right path by splitting the sentence into tokens with `split()`. You then get an array of all the tokens in your sentence. All that remains to do is to iterate over that array and filter out any tokens that doesn't start with the letter `b`, like this:

```
var sentence = "My baby has a nice belly";
var tokens = sentence.split(" ");
var bTokens = tokens.filter(function(token) {
    return /^b/.test(token);
}).join(" ");
document.getElementById("mytextarea").value = bTokens;
```

Comment: I am somewhere along these lines for the input;                                    var inputString = document.getElementById( "inputField" ).value;
   var tokens = inputString.split( " " ); 
   
    var bTokens = tokens.filter(function(token) {
    return /^b/.test(token);
}).join(" ");
document.getElementById("mytextarea").value = bTokens;
   
    var results = document.getElementById( "results" );
    results.innerHTML = "<p>The sentence split into words is: </p>" + 
      "<p class = 'indent'>" + 
      tokens.join( "</p><p class = 'indent'>" ) + "</p>";